# Django REST Framework : update() based on query string parameter

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Is it possible to modify a ViewSet's update() function to update based on a query string parameter instead of a URL resource name or the request body?

For example, I want trigger something like this:

```
payload = {'field' : '2'}
r = requests.put("http://127.0.0.1:9876/job-defs?job-def-id=2", data=payload)
```

and have this update my field when job-def-id = 2.

What I have so far is this:

```
class JobDefinitionsViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                        mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                        mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                        mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                        viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    serializer_class = JobDefinitionsSerializer

    def update(self, request, pk=None):
        job_def_id = self.request.query_params.get('job-def-id', None)
        super(JobDefinitionsViewSet, self).update(self, request, pk=job_def_id)

    ...
    # other unrelated code
    ...
```

I'm not too sure how to continue. 
I want to reuse as much as the update() function from mixins.UpdateModelMixin as possible. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you seem to be in the right direction. Is it not working? What is the error/log/effect?

Comment: Expected view JobDefinitionsViewSet to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly.

Comment: To fit the API design, I don't want to include the "pk" as a URL resource. This works so far for get : 'list' and post : 'create'.

Comment: alright, then you might want to drive the whole thing not through GenericViewSet and its routers/urlconf, but through GenericAPIView

Comment: why not override the `get_object` method so that it uses your `pk` to fetch the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to use the same url for listing and for retrieving the details of the entity, discriminating on the presence of the url parameter `job-def-id`, here is a crazy idea:

```
class JobDefinitionsAllInOneView(mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                                 mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                                 mixins.ListModelMixin,
                                 mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                                 generics.GenericAPIView):

    queryset = JobDefinitions.objects.all()
    serializer_class = JobDefinitionsSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        job_def_id = self.request.query_params.get('job-def-id', None)
        if job_def_id is not None:
            self.kwargs['pk'] = job_def_id
        return super(JobDefinitionsAllInOneView, self).get_object()

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        job_def_id = self.request.query_params.get('job-def-id', None)
        if job_def_id is not None:
            # return the details
            return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            # return a list
            return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I haven't tried it yet. I had a look at the source code [here](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/4248a8d3fc725d9ae3fe7aaaad7ee12479ab07ab/rest_framework/generics.py) for get_object and [here](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/4248a8d3fc725d9ae3fe7aaaad7ee12479ab07ab/rest_framework/mixins.py) for the mixins

Comment: Very interesting approach. The request is going through but the payload is getting dropped. (PS. there are 2 minor grammatical errors: viewsets.GenericAPIView should be generics.GenericAPIView and self.kwargs['pk'] = self.job_def_id should just be job_def_id)